# AdventureWorks2012: "The FILE SIZE property is incorrect" error while trying to attach sample database "Adventure Works for SQL Server 2012"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, testing, development

I am trying to attach the sample databases, for example, `AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf` from [codeplex "Adventure Works for SQL Server 2012"](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330) into a MS SQL Server 2012 (default) instances on a a virtual machines under MS Windows Server 2008 and MS Windows 7.

Each time I am getting the error:

> The header for file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf' is
>   not a valid database file header. The FILE SIZE property is incorrect.
>   (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.3128&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5172&LinkId=20476

What can be done to attach the MS SQL Server 2012 sample databases?

Tried to install these sample databases ак the script(s), also always getting the error, the different one, about which I shall ask in a separate question.

Comment: Are you sure your don't simply have a corrupt/mis-downloaded file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading from [AdventureWorks Databases – 2012, 2008R2 and 2008](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587).

This might be due to corrupt installs.

Comment: Thanks. It has worked though I already reinstalled the server and computer since the question

Comment: And AdventureWorksDW2012 I could install from [AdventureWorksDW Databases – 2012, 2008R2 and 2008](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/105902)